# Better Random Number Testing Suites

Tags: random

I wanted to generate multiple random number sets and test them using conventional random number testing suites. I came across the NIST suite of testing, Diehard suite and a few other commonly mentioned ones.

These seemed to be pretty old. Are there any newer test suites that are deemed better for the modern generation schemes or if not which of these are the better choices for testing pseudo random number sets of relatively small numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Ideally we want PRNG output to be indistinguishable from i.i.d. uniform behavior.  The test suites evaluate PRNG output for various properties implicit in the assumptions of uniformity and independence.  Our knowledge of those properties is old,  but age does not alter the validity and utility of that knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends a bit on what you want the random numbers for. Assuming you are doing simulations, Monte-Carlo methods, or most other non-security uses, testu01 as mentioned in another answer is very good. Also practrand http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/
and gjrand http://gjrand.sourceforge.net/

Lots of caveats. None is really easy to use out of the box. It would help to have some C or C++ experience. None can prove that the prng is good. They can find certain classes of faults if they exist (and lots of popular prngs have faults that at least one of these three suites can find).

Answer (score 0):

TestU01 from prof P.L'Ecuyer seems to be pretty good choice, and it is not that old as you imply http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html